# Java задача на использование Swing

Tags: java, swing, gui, awt

Необходимо написать программу, в которой при нажатии мышки создаётся квадратик синего цвета, при двойном нажатии на синий квадратик цвет меняется на красный, и при двойном нажатии на красный квадратик удаляется.
Только начал изучение Swing и пока плохо в этом разбираюсь. В данном коде не меняется цвет с синего на красный, и цвет квадратика выделяется по контуру, а нужно с заливкой.

````
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new MouseFrame();
            frame.setTitle("MouseTest");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
class MouseFrame extends JFrame
{
    public MouseFrame()
    {
        add(new MouseComponent());
        pack();
    }
}
class MouseComponent extends JComponent
{
    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 900;
    private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 600;

    private static final int SIDELENGTH = 10;
    private ArrayList<Rectangle2D> squares;
    private Rectangle2D current; // the square containing the mouse cursor
    Graphics2D g2;
    public MouseComponent()
    {
        squares = new ArrayList<>();
        current = null;

        addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionHandler());
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() { return new Dimension(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT); }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        // draw all squares
        for (Rectangle2D r : squares) {
            g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2.draw(r);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds the first square containing a point.
     * @param p a point
     * @return the first square that contains p
     */
    public Rectangle2D find(Point2D p)
    {
        for (Rectangle2D r : squares)
        {
            if (r.contains(p)) return r;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a square to the collection.
     * @param p the center of the square
     */
    public void add(Point2D p)
    {
        double x = p.getX();
        double y = p.getY();

        current = new Rectangle2D.Double(x - SIDELENGTH / 2, y - SIDELENGTH / 2, SIDELENGTH,
                SIDELENGTH);
        squares.add(current);
        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Removes a square from the collection.
     * @param s the square to remove
     */
    public void remove(Rectangle2D s)
    {
        if (s == null) return;
        if (s == current) current = null;
        squares.remove(s);
        repaint();
    }

    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
        {
            // add a new square if the cursor isn't inside a square
            current = find(event.getPoint());
            if (current == null) add(event.getPoint());
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
        {
            // remove the current square if double clicked
            current = find(event.getPoint());
            if (current != null && event.getClickCount() >= 2 ){
                remove(current);
            }
        }
    }

    private class MouseMotionHandler implements MouseMotionListener
    {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event)
        {
            // set the mouse cursor to cross hairs if it is inside
            // a rectangle

            if (find(event.getPoint()) == null) setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
            else setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
        {
            if (current != null)
            {
                int x = event.getX();
                int y = event.getY();

                // drag the current rectangle to center it at (x, y)
                current.setFrame(x - SIDELENGTH / 2, y - SIDELENGTH / 2, SIDELENGTH, SIDELENGTH);
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Заполненный прямоугольник - это метод `fill()`. А вот с определением цвета придется немного усложнить код. Поскольку `Rectangle2D` не содержит цвет в себе, его придется хранить в каком-нибудь собственном классе, как вариант, унаследоваться от `Rectangle2D`. Потом в `MouseHandler`-e добавить нужные условия... Как-то так

Comment: За метод ```fill()``` огромное спасибо, решение одной проблемы есть. Теперь буду думать как изменить цвет

Comment: Обращайтесь )). Я бы советовал все-таки унаследоваться от `Rectangle2D`. Придется переопределить абстрактные методы, но кто сказал, что будет легко )))